# Microsoft Access New Tab button in Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, button, tabs

What I'm trying to do is create a form where people input data. They're basically going to be tracking what they've done on a computer.

I'd like to have one main form that starts off with a brief intro and then a tab where they're going to be entering the information.

I'd like them to have the option of adding new tabs, so they can track their actions with multiple computers at once.

What would I need to have the button do in order to open a new tab next to the existing one?

Comment: Define "tab".  Do you mean tabs in a tab control, or do you mean a new form (which adds tab in the Access environment)?

Comment: You want to open multiple instances of the same data entry form? That requires VBA, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-35.html. I don't used Tabbed Documents, I use Overlapping Windows configuration. This is an Options setting for the database.

Comment: How 'bout a continuous sub-form instead?

Comment: Tabs in the terms of the "tab control," yes.

Comment: And basically, this would be for new forms. Say I wanted to work on 5 different computer systems. Then, I'd open 5 different trackers, each in their own tab with their own information.